# Assets @ Android

Tags: java, android

I am having problems listing assets in my apk file, my aim is to be able to get the direct path of one of my assets and pass it to native code using JNI
 1. I have added a file to the assets folder of my project
 2. **I have verified that the file exist in the '/assets' folder** of the apk file resulting of compilation of my project
 3. at the 'onCreate' function of my Activity I do the following:
      AssetManager am = this.getApplicationContext().getAssets();
      String strAssets[] = am.list("/assets");
 4. strAssets.length is always zero
 5. I was getting the same for "./assets" and "assets"

What am I doing wrong here? why can't I list the available assets?

Any help will be appreciated.

~Nadav at sophin

Comment: What do you wanna do ? And please take some time to format your question so that it is clear

Comment: and explain your intention, show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`am.list("/assets")` lookes for a folder called 'assets' within your assets folder. Just use `am.list("")` to get all files.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to the list method is the path **within** the assets folder.  if it's at the root, shouldn't you get results from either an empty string or a single slash?

[AssetManager.list(String path)](http://bit.ly/yllBkw)

Comment: I do get a list of files when calling am.list("/"), however, this list doesn't include the files I have added to the 'assets' folder of the project